# What's Excel's minimum initial configuration?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I frequently need to re-start Excel. I would like to configure/start some parameters to launch Excel more quickly. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Google search produces very confusing results.

Comment: Which version? Multiple versions out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An other way to look at your question is around minimizing the number of "add-in's".
In that case, you can uncheck all "COM add-in's" and "Normal add-in's". Also ckeck if the start directory ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\XLSTART") does not contain any add-in's.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure that I understand your question, but I take it that you want to quickly start Excel (on a windows PC) without having to search through the Windows start menu.

1. Drag the Excel icon from e.g. your desktop into the quick launch bar next to the start button (you might have to remove the check mark next to the "Lock the taskbar" first when you right-click in the taskbar).
2. e.g. use AutoHotKey to assign launch commands to certain key combinations. In this example, I use [Win]+x to launch Excel:   #x::Run excel
3. Firmly "pin" your Excel icon in the start menu and rename it so the first letter is unique. I use the opensource "Classic Start menu" and drag the excel icon from e.g. the desktop first onto the windows start button and, while holding the mouse button,  continue to move the icon in the top section above "programs". Rename the icon to e.g. "Excel". As long as there is no other icon in your start menu that starts with an "E", you can start Excel by pressing [Start], [E].

If my interpretation of your question is wrong, let me know.

Regards,

Robert Ilbrink

Answer (score 1):

Hate to be so short but: don't close it. Nothing is as fast as just keeping it open. With Windows 7's task bar this is very easy to do as once you pin it to the task bar the same icon will launch Excel if it isn't running or open it when it is already running.